# Scan Matching Algorithm giving wrong values for translation but right value for rotation

Tags: python, robotics, least-squares, slam-algorithm

I've already posted it on robotics.stackexchange but I had no relevant answer.

I'm currently developing a SLAM software on a robot, and I tried the Scan Matching algorithm to solve the odometry problem.

I read this article :
[Metric-Based Iterative Closest Point Scan Matching
for Sensor Displacement Estimation](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~montesan/web/pdfs/minguez06TRO.pdf)

I found it really well explained, and I strictly followed the formulas given in the article to implement the algorithm.

You can see my implementation in python there :
[ScanMatching.py](https://github.com/pierrolelivier/SLAMScanMatching/blob/master/ScanMatching.py)

The problem I have is that, during my tests, the right rotation was found, but the translation was totally false. The values of translation are extremely high.

Do you have guys any idea of what can be the problem in my code ?

Otherwise, should I post my question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange ?

The ICP part should be correct, as I tested it many times, but the Least Square Minimization doesn't seem to give good results.

As you noticed, I used many bigfloat.BigFloat values, cause sometimes the max float was not big enough to contain some values.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you already solved this issue.

I didn't read the full article, but I noticed it is rather old.

IMHO (I'm not the expert here), I would try bunching specific algorithms, like feature detection and description to get a point cloud, descriptor matcher to relate points, bundle adjustement to get the rototraslation matrix.

I myself am going to try sba (http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/), or more specifically cvsba (http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/39/) because I'm on opencv.

If you have enough cpu/gpu power, give a chance to AKAZE feature detector and descriptor.